# Convert stack into data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

After stacking several datasets, I need to convert the stack into a dataframe again in order to produce a boxplot. It would be great to get advice on possible commands for this task.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: If this is an R question, use the [tag:r] tag. Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean for R (you should always make it clear what software you mean!)

If you have a variable that indicates which group they're from, you don't need to unstack.

e.g. see the examples under [?boxplot](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/boxplot.html) - paste them in and try them

Here's an example:

```
boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, col = "lightgray",boxwex=.4)
```

[image: boxplot of InsectSprays data]

That data is stacked:

```
> head(InsectSprays,15)
   count spray
1     10     A
2      7     A
3     20     A
4     14     A
5     14     A
6     12     A
7     10     A
8     23     A
9     17     A
10    20     A
11    14     A
12    13     A
13    11     B
14    17     B
15    21     B
...
```